# Read bit range from byte array

Tags: c#, byte, bit-manipulation, bit

I am looking for a method that will enable me to get a range of bits. For example if I have the binary data

**`0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1`**  (2 bytes)

I might need to get data from range bit 3 to 9. In other words I would be interested in:

**0 1 0 1 1 0 `1 1 1 1 0 1 0` 1 1 1**

so in short I will like to construct the method:

```
 byte[] Read(byte[] data, int left, int right){ 

     // implementation
 }
```

so that if I pass the data `new byte[]{91,215}, 3, 9`  I will get `byte[]{122}`  (note byte 91 and 215 = `0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1` and byte 122 = `1 1 1 1 0 1 0` same binary data as the example.

It would be nice if I could use the `<<` operator on byte arrays such as doing something like:

```
  byte[] myArray = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
  var shift = myArray << 2;
```

**If you are interested to know why I need this functionality:**

I am creating a project on a board and often need to read and write values to the memory. The cdf, sfr, or ddf (refereed to as chip definition file) contains information about a particular chip. That file may look like:

```
;     Name                            Zone      Address     Bytesize  Displaybase Bitrange
;     ----                            ----      -------     --------  ----------- --------

sfr = "SPI0_CONTROL"              , "Memory", 0x40001000,        4, base=16
sfr = "SPI0_CONTROL.SPH"          , "Memory", 0x40001000,        4, base=16,    bitRange=25-25
sfr = "SPI0_CONTROL.SPO"          , "Memory", 0x40001000,        4, base=16,    bitRange=24-24
sfr = "SPI0_CONTROL.TXRXDFCOUNT"  , "Memory", 0x40001000,        4, base=16,    bitRange=8-23
sfr = "SPI0_CONTROL.INT_TXUR"     , "Memory", 0x40001000,        4, base=16,    bitRange=7-7
sfr = "SPI0_CONTROL.INT_RXOVF"    , "Memory", 0x40001000,        4, base=16,    bitRange=6-6
```

Since I am reading a lot of variables (sometimes 80 times per second) I will like to have an efficient algorithm. I guess my approach would be that if the bytesize is 8 then I will create a long from those 8 bytes then use the `<<` and `>>` operators in order to get what I need. if the bytesize if 4 then I will create an int and use the `<<` and `>>` operators but How will I do it if I need to read 16 bytes though? **I guess my question should been how to implement the `<<` and `>>` operators on custom struct types.**

Comment: 80 times per second?  That's the same speed that a 3D game draws frames to the screen.  You don't need a very efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class from *System.Collections*.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.100).aspx that's is :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you could help a "bit stream". There is an implementation of such a concept [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12261/A-BitStream-Class-for-the-NET-Framework). Take a look, perhaps it fits your needs.

Comment: Be wary of that article/implementation. The 64-bit read/write operations don't decode/encode data correctly. And it doesn't look like it (the text or code) has been updated in over 7 years now.

Answer (score 2):

The [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class in .NET 4+ takes a `Byte[]` in its constructor and has left and right shift operators.

Answer (score 0):

It's been 10 years since this question and I could not yet find a simple C# implementation that extracts a range of bits from a byte array using bitwise operations.
Here's how you can do it using simple bitwise operations:

```
public static class ByteExtensions
{
    public const int BitsPerByte = 8;

    /// <summary>
    /// Extracts a range of bits from a byte array into a new byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytes">The byte array to extract the range from.</param>
    /// <param name="start">The 0-based start index of the bit.</param>
    /// <param name="length">The number of bits to extract.</param>
    /// <returns>A new <see cref="byte"/> array with the extracted bits.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Thrown if <paramref name="start"/> or <paramref name="length"/> are out of range.</exception>
    public static byte[] GetBitRange(this byte[] bytes, int start, int length)
    { 
        // Calculate the length of the input byte array in bits 
        int maxLength = bytes.Length * BitsPerByte;

        int end = start + length;

        // Range validations
        if (start >= maxLength || start < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(start), start, $"Start must non-negative and lesser than {maxLength}");
        }
        if (length < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length), length, $"Length must be non-negative");
        }
        if (end > maxLength)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length), length, $"Range length must be less than or equal to {maxLength}");
        }

        // Calculate the length of the new byte array and allocate
        var (byteLength, remainderLength) = Math.DivRem(length, BitsPerByte);
        byte[] result = new byte[byteLength + (remainderLength == 0 ? 0 : 1)];

        // Iterate through each byte in the new byte array
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            
            // Compute each of the 8 bits of the ith byte
            // Stop if start index >= end index (rest of the bits in the current byte will be 0 by default)
            for (int j = 0; j < BitsPerByte && start < end; j++)
            {
                var (byteIndex, bitIndex) = Math.DivRem(start++, BitsPerByte); // Note the increment(++) in start
                int currentBitIndex = j;
      
                result[i] |= (byte)(((bytes[byteIndex] >> bitIndex) & 1) << currentBitIndex);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

**1. Allocate a new byte[] for the range**

The `GetBitRange(..)` method above first (after validation) calculates the length of the new byte array(length in bytes) using the `length` parameter(length in bits) and allocates this array(`result`).

The outer loop iterates through each byte in `result` and the inner loop iterates through each of the 8 bits in the i<sup>th</sup> byte.

**2. Extracting a bit from a byte**

In the inner loop, the method calculates the index of the byte in the input array `bytes` which contains the bit indexed by `start`. It is the `bitIndex`<sup>th</sup> bit in the `byteIndex`<sup>th</sup> byte. To extract this bit, you perform the following operations:

```
int nextBit = (bytes[byteIndex] >> bitIndex) & 1;
```

Shift the `bitIndex`<sup>th</sup> bit in `bytes[byteIndex]` to the rightmost position so it is the least significant bit(LSB). And then perform a bitwise AND with `1`. (A bitwise AND with `1` extracts only the LSB and makes the rest of the bits 0.)

**3. Setting a bit in a byte**

Now, `nextBit` is the next bit I need to add to my output byte array(`result`). Since, I'm currently working on the j<sup>th</sup> bit of my i<sup>th</sup> byte of `result` in my inner loop, I need to set that bit to `nextBit`. This is done as:

```
int currentBitIndex = j;
result[i] |= (byte) (nextBit << currentBitIndex);
```

Shift `nextBit` `j` times to the left (since I want to set the `j`<sup>th</sup> bit). Now to set the bit, I perform a bitwise OR between the shifted bit and `result[i]`. This sets the `j`<sup>th</sup> bit in `result[i]`.

The steps 2 & 3 described above are implemented in the method as a single step:

```
result[i] |= (byte)(((bytes[byteIndex] >> bitIndex) & 1) << currentBitIndex);
```

Two important things to consider here:

- *Byte Endianness*
- *Bit Numbering*

#### Byte Endianness

The above implementation indexes into the input byte array in big endian order. So, as per the example in the question,

```
new byte[]{ 91 , 215 }.GetBitRange(3, 8)
```

does not return `122` but returns `235` instead. This is because the example in the question expects the answer in little-endian format.
To use little-endian format, a simple reversal of the output array does the job. Even better is to change `byteIndex` in the implementation:

```
byteIndex = bytes.Length - 1 - byteIndex;
```

#### Bit Numbering

- [Bit numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) determines if the least significant bit is the first bit in the byte ([LSB 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#LSB_0_bit_numbering)) or the most significant bit is the first bit ([MSB 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#MSB_0_bit_numbering)).
- The implementation above assumes LSB0 bit numbering.
- To use MSB0, change the bit indices as follows:

```
currentBitIndex = BitsPerByte - 1 - currentBitIndex;
bitIndex = BitsPerByte - 1 - bitIndex;
```

#### Extending for endianness and bit numbering

Here is the full method supporting both types of endianness as well as bit numbering:

```
public enum Endianness
{
    BigEndian,
    LittleEndian
}
```

```
public enum BitNumbering
{
    Lsb0,
    Msb0
}
```

```
public static class ByteExtensions
{
    public const int BitsPerByte = 8;

    public static byte[] GetBitRange(
        this byte[] bytes, 
        int start, 
        int length, 
        Endianness endianness, 
        BitNumbering bitNumbering)
    { 
        // Calculate the length of the input byte array in bits 
        int maxLength = bytes.Length * BitsPerByte;

        int end = start + length;

        // Range validations
        if (start >= maxLength || start < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(start), start, $"Start must non-negative and lesser than {maxLength}");
        }
        if (length < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length), length, $"Length must be non-negative");
        }
        if (end > maxLength)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length), length, $"Range length must be less than or equal to {maxLength}");
        }

        // Calculate the length of the new byte array and allocate
        var (byteLength, remainderLength) = Math.DivRem(length, BitsPerByte);
        byte[] result = new byte[byteLength + (remainderLength == 0 ? 0 : 1)];

        // Iterate through each byte in the new byte array
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {

            // Compute each of the 8 bits of the ith byte
            // Stop if start index >= end index (rest of the bits in the current byte will be 0 by default)
            for (int j = 0; j < BitsPerByte && start < end; j++)
            {
                var (byteIndex, bitIndex) = Math.DivRem(start++, BitsPerByte); // Note the increment(++) in start
                int currentBitIndex = j;
                
                // Adjust for MSB 0
                if (bitNumbering is BitNumbering.Msb0)
                {
                    currentBitIndex = 7 - currentBitIndex;
                    bitIndex = 7 - bitIndex;
                }
                // Adjust for little-endian
                if (endianness is Endianness.LittleEndian)
                {
                    byteIndex = bytes.Length - 1 - byteIndex;
                }
                result[i] |= (byte)(((bytes[byteIndex] >> bitIndex) & 1) << currentBitIndex);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```